# Can Google Cloud Compute connect to Mandrill for SMTP relay?

Tags: mandrill

I'm using Mandrill service, now I want to use this service to replay instance email, you know that instance blocked 25 port, so will use 2525 port for this replay, is Google Cloud Compute support Mandrill ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have personally used mandrill and found no issues working with Google cloud as long as the port is 2525.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work fine as Mandrill does indeed support port 2525 which google compute engine can use.